# How to get function object inside a function (Python)

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, introspection

I want to have something like

```
def x():
  print get_def_name()
```

but not necessarily know the name of `x`.

Ideally it would return `'x'` where x would be the name of the function.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using Python's built-in inspect library.

You can read more of its documentation if you want to handle more complicated cases, but this snippet will work for you:

```
from inspect import getframeinfo, currentframe

def test_func_name():
    return getframeinfo(currentframe()).function

print(test_func_name())
```

Answer (score 7):

Functions in Python are objects, and as it happens those objects do have an attribute containing the name they were defined with:

```
>>> def x():
...     pass
...
>>> print x.__name__
x
```

So, a naïve approach might be this:

```
>>> def x():
...     print x.__name__
... 
>>> x()
x
```

That seems to work. However, since you had to know the name of `x` inside the function in order to do that, you haven't really gained anything; you might have well just have done this:

```
def x():
    print "x"
```

In fact, though, it's worse than that, because the `__name__` attribute only refers to the name the function was *defined* with. If it gets bound to another name, it won't behave as you expect:

```
>>> y = x
>>> y()
x
```

Even worse, if the original name is no longer around, it won't work at all:

```
>>> del x
>>> y()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in x
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

This second problem is one you can actually get around, although it's not pretty. The trick is to write a decorator that can pass the function's name into it as an argument:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def introspective(func):
...     __name__ = func.__name__
...     @wraps(func)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...         return func(__name__=__name__, *args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> @introspective
... def x(__name__):
...     print __name__
... 
>>> x()
x
>>> y = x
>>> y()
x
>>> del x
>>> y()
x
```

... although as you can see, you're still only getting back the name the function was defined with, not the one it happens to be bound to right now.

**In practice, the short (and correct) answer is "don't do that".** It's a fundamental fact of Python that objects don't know what name (or names) they're bound to - if you think your function needs that information, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to declare an anonymous function and it would return a reference to the new function object.

In Python, you can get a trivial anonymous function object with `lambda` but for a complex function it must have a name.  But any function object is in fact an object and you can pass references around to it, so the name doesn't matter.

```
# lambda
sqr = lambda n: n**2
assert sqr(2) == 4
assert sqr(3) == 9

# named function
def f(n):
    return n**2

sqr = f
assert sqr(2) == 4
assert sqr(3) == 9
```

Note that this function does have a name, `f`, but the name doesn't really matter here.  We set the name `sqr` to the function object reference and use that name.  We could put the function reference into a list or other data structure if we wanted to.

You could re-use the name of the function:

```
def f(n):
    return n**2
sqr = f

def f(n):
    return n**3
cube = f
```

So, while Python doesn't really support full anonymous functions, you can get the same effect.  It's not really a problem that you have to give functions a name.

If you really don't want the function to have a name, you can unbind the name:

```
def f(n):
    return n**2

lst = [f]  # save function reference in a list
del(f)  # unbind the name
```

Now the only way to access this function is through the list; the name of the function is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution as Vazirani's, but I did a step forward to get the function object based on the name. Here is my solution:

```
import inspect

def named_func():
    func_name = inspect.stack()[0].function
    func_obj = inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_locals[func_name]
    print(func_name, func_obj, func_obj.xxx)

named_func.xxx = 15
named_func()
```

Output is

```
named_func <function named_func at 0x7f3bc84622f0> 15
```

Unfortunately I cannot do this with lambda function. I keep trying.