# How to get a variable from an outside function?

Tags: python

I would like to get a variable which contains dict with important values from another project, and it is in a function, for instance:

Foo is an external module, it's not part of my project.

```
# bar.py

def bar():
    qux = {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}
```

I want to get `qux` value in my project:

```
# main.py
from foo.bar import bar

print(bar.qux)
```

But when I try to get directly, I receive:

```
ERROR: 'function' object has no attribute 'qux'
```

Is there any way to do this? I'm running Python 3.8.

Comment: No, this is a _local_ variable, and it's only accessible within this function

Comment: I think you've stripped out some necessary information while constructing your example. Is `bar()` actually a class method? It has a `self` parameter which suggests that it is inside a class. Also, is the assignment actually `self.qux = {...}`? It needs to assign the dict to a field, not a local variable. As written, `qux` is a local variable and there's no way to access it from the outside.

Comment: If you think about it, it doesn't make much sense. As in the general case, local function variables are subject to a specific call of the function. So how can you staticly get a value of a dynamic variable?

Comment: No, is not a class method, there is no class described in that example.

Comment: You cannot access a local variable of a function from outside the function. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Is there any hack, using inspect or function attributes? I not looking for a regular solution since it's a local variable.

Comment: Can you address what @chepner said? Could you provide some core context for this?

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing functons with classes here. But to do this with minimal changes to your code, you'd want to do

```py
# bar.py

def bar(self):
    return {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}
```

```py
# main.py
from foo.bar import bar

print(bar())
```

Comment: I believe that according to OP he doesn't have access to `foo`...

Comment: No! I need to access the variable in an external function, exactly as I described. Again, It's an external module, I can't change anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're trying to get a variable that's declared inside a function, and treating it like its an object.

Just change:

```
def bar(self):
    qux = {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}
    return qux
```

and then you can get the object inside bar as:

```
from foo.bar import bar

print(bar())
```

But this is just redundant; why declare an object inside a function, just to access it?

Inside your foo.py, you should just declare the object like normal and access it via:

```
from foo import qux
```

EDIT:
Since you don't have access to foo, perhaps this answer is better suited:

> [How to get function object inside a function (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250118/how-to-get-function-object-inside-a-function-python)

Since all functions are objects in Python, this is technically possible.

Comment: But he doesn't have access to foo

Comment: How will the function's name help OP (which is what your link provides)?

Answer (score -1):

Use of `self` in the function is bad for 2 reasons. First, it is not being used and second it is confusing as `self` is the default Object Orientated syntax (classes).

To fix your function remove self and return your value:

```
def bar():
    return {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}
```

But I think you want something OO, so wrap it in a class:

```
class Foo:

    def bar(self):
        self.qux = {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}

foo = Foo()
foo.bar() 
foo.qux
```

But that is bad practice as an `__init__` should be used:

```
class Foo:

    # qux = None also an option, but I recommend __init__

    def __init__(self):
        self.qux = None

    def bar(self):
        self.qux = {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}

foo = Foo()
foo.bar() 
foo.qux
```

Or just go class style, common in model definitions and other Python fun:

```
class Foo:
    qux = {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "charlie": 3}
foo = Foo()
foo.qux
# will also work in this circumstance
Foo.qux
```

Comment: What self!? I didn't write anything about class, it just a function in an external method, there is no self. there is no class!

Comment: @uilianries  `bar.py` has `def bar(self):`. "just function in an external method" is ambiguous as a method is a product of a class.  Or you could be meaning a nested function in a method in a class?  Also possibly a nested function in a function? All of this is valid in Python.